# Android Studio unhandled exception warnings

Tags: android, android-studio

When I enter certain lines like `JSONObject` decoding or date parsing, the app will not compile as the compiler gives an `UnhandledException` warning and I have to wrap the call in a `try/catch block` before the app will compile. Can this be disabled so that I don't need to write the `try/catch block`?

Comment: post some code for getting solution

Comment: Doesn't matter on Android Studio or in Eclipse, decoding `JSONObject` should be wrapper in try/catch or it won't compile in both IDE's. That's because the function `getJSONObject` or `JSONObject`'s constructor throws an exception which you should catch.

Comment: @Android-Developer Thanks, if you post that as an answer I will accept

Comment: You can suppress warnings, but you cannot suppress the fact that your program will crash when unhandled exception will arise. Just catch exceptions, friend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comment doesn't matter if you are using Android Studio or Eclipse or any other IDE, while using code which showing error where you should wrap your code with `try / catch` block, you can't disable this. You should just add the block and change your code so you can handle the rest of your function or class properly if this exception is thrown in some point of program execution.

For throwing and catching exceptions in Java you can read more about here:

[Java Programming : Throwing and Catching Exceptions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions)

and for better explanation of which exceptions should be wrapped with `try/catch` block and which not, here are two good examples:

[Java Exception Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) , and [Java Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Comment: Writing a try/catch will make the warning go away and I agree that in most cases this should be done, but there are situations where the IDE can be wrong and you would want to suppress this warning. An example being, if you're stubbing a method that could throw an exception. The fact that you're stubbing it will guarantee that it returns a value.

Comment: +1 for "or class properly if this exception is thrown in point of program execution", like this:
- protected void parseJSON() throws Exception { your code here; }